# Where can I get the default /etc/hosts file for Debian Sid?

Tags: debian, sid

I've somehow deleted `/etc/hosts` on my testing system, which is Debian Sid. Now I want to install the default `/etc/hosts`. I tried `dpkg -S /etc/hosts` to find out which package contains `/etc/hosts`, but none was found. Where can I download it from ?

Comment: Just do a quick local Sid install in Virtualbox and find out for yourself?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `/etc/hosts` file is written [via `debian-installer`](http://wiki.debian.org/ConfigPackages), it does not exist as a packaged file.

The following is my `/etc/hosts` from a default install:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       hostname.fqdn.example.com    hostname

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

For more details of the syntax see Debian Reference section [**The hostname resolution**](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch05.en.html#_te_hostname_resolution).

Update:

Since I feel this answer has garnered more upvotes than I had expected, I did a little finger-work for you, in return. :)

The actual package used by `debian-installer`, which contains the `/etc/hosts` logic, is named [`net-cfg`](http://packages.debian.org/sid/netcfg).  More specifically, two files, `netcfg.h` and `netcfg-common.c` handle the logic of building the `/etc/hosts` file.

`netcfg.h` has `#define`s for both the file itself, and the IPv6 entries:

```
#define HOSTS_FILE      "/etc/hosts"
...<snip>...
#define IPV6_HOSTS \
"# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts\n" \
"::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback\n" \
"fe00::0 ip6-localnet\n" \
"ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix\n" \
"ff02::1 ip6-allnodes\n" \
"ff02::2 ip6-allrouters\n"
```

`netcfg-common.c` contains the dirty work, populating the info in `/etc/hosts`:

```
if ((fp = file_open(HOSTS_FILE, "w"))) {
    char ptr1[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];

    fprintf(fp, "127.0.0.1\tlocalhost");

    if (ipaddress.s_addr) {
        inet_ntop (AF_INET, &ipaddress, ptr1, sizeof(ptr1));
        if (domain_nodot && !empty_str(domain_nodot))
            fprintf(fp, "\n%s\t%s.%s\t%s\n", ptr1, hostname, domain_nodot, hostname);
        else
            fprintf(fp, "\n%s\t%s\n", ptr1, hostname);
    } else {
#if defined(__linux__) || defined(__GNU__)
        if (domain_nodot && !empty_str(domain_nodot))
            fprintf(fp, "\n127.0.1.1\t%s.%s\t%s\n", hostname, domain_nodot, hostname);
        else
            fprintf(fp, "\n127.0.1.1\t%s\n", hostname);
#else
        fprintf(fp, "\t%s\n", hostname);
#endif
    }

    fprintf(fp, "\n" IPV6_HOSTS);

    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: Here are a couple of links to [back](https://salsa.debian.org/installer-team/netcfg/blob/1.158/netcfg-common.c#L1157) it [up](https://salsa.debian.org/installer-team/netcfg/blob/1.158/netcfg.h#L40). Do you feel like looking into where `debian-installer` invokes `netcfg` by any chance? :)

Answer (score 1):

Unchecked on Debian, but it should be

```
::1                     localhost localhost.my.domain
127.0.0.1               localhost localhost.my.domain
```

(if you do not use IPv6 then you can ignore the line starting with ::1)

Edit: The file is probably the base installation, not from an additional package.